# How to access collection object in view

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

[image]

this is query

```
$product = Product::with('categories')->take(5)->get();
```

I can't access relation on image 
thank for answer

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? Are you passing the `$product` collection to the view? How are you accessing it in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// for clarity name this plural as this is a collection too
$products = Product::with('categories')->take(5)->get();

// then in your view:
@foreach ($products as $product)
  $product->categories; // accessible like that
```